# Microsoft Storage Spaces Extremely Variable Write Speeds

Tags: windows, hard-drive, raid, storage-spaces

I am using Microsoft Windows 10 Storage Spaces in Simple (not Parity or Mirroring) mode with 3 x external 8TB 5400 RPM drives.

Whilst transferring 10TB of data from a separate 12TB external 5400 RPM drive I have noticed extremely variable write speeds. Towards the end it was running at 10KB/s, however, it also reached speeds as high as 240MB/s.

Storage Spaces is using the default Simple settings. All external drives are connected using USB 3.0. The write cache is enabled for all drives (with external power settings enabled). The drive temperatures are all within 40-45 degrees C. The PC has ample CPU (16x 4.2Ghz cores, largely idle) and RAM (66GB, 27% in use).

Can anyone help diagnose the cause of this and, ideally, a solution?

Comment: How large are the files? Large files copy faster than small ones. I've always thought Windows to be particularly slow at file copies, though i've no idea why. So much so that I find it's faster to do a full backup by hooking the drive up to my Mac over USB 2 than to run it from Win over SATA.

Comment: Wow, that is interesting. There is a real mix of files - everywhere from multiple 100s of GB to a few KB. I did try (very loosely) to see if it was slower transferring the smaller files by just looking at the filename (e.g. did it transfer faster when on a single large file) but this unscientific approach didn't tell me much. One more thing to note - there was a large 'average response time' for the Storage Spaces drive in Resource Manager - this may be helpful to know

Comment: Yeah, that might be relevant; both the fact that they're mechanical 5400 RPM drives and the fact that they're USB-connected will give you good bulk throughput when copying large files, but poor latency when making tons of small requests all around. Are the drives at least connected via UAS and not traditional "bulk transport mass storage" mode? (UAS has command queuing; BT does not.)  Are they connected through _separate_ adapters? (I've had a 2-disk USB 3.0 SATA dock that _could not_ talk to both disks in parallel; when it was busy waiting for response from one, you couldn't use the other.)

Comment: If I am checking correctly, the 3 drives in the Storage Pool are UAS but the one I was transferring from was not (I think). It could be read speed limitation? Although that doesn't match with the high Average Response time on the write disks. I have just restarted now that the transfer is finished and Average Response Time is now 0 (from multiple seconds) and a download to the drive over Gbit connection is achieving 112MB/s (likely capped out by the connection). Unfortunately, you can't reboot in the middle of a 10TB data transfer! I'm still very curious to find the cause in case it recurs